# Strange issue when uploading a Laravel project to shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel-5, shared-hosting

I have created a Laravel 2 project and uploaded it to a web host, but the website gives a 500 error. I have given 777 permmisions to storge and subfolders. I cleared the views cache but that didn't solve the problem.

I want to know, why is this problem occurring?
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqGQa.png)

the public/.htacess file 

    
        Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: define `RewriteBase /`

Comment: Where to define , in htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Could be a number of issues. Check the following:

1. Have you run `composer install` to install the vendor files required for Laravel to run?
2. Run `chmod -R 777 storage` (as you have already tried)
3. Run `chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache`

Hopefully these steps will help you resolve the issue. If you still have issues, see if you can locate the `error_log` file on your server and see if it points to the issue.